# Choosing a domain name with joined words is good for SEO?

Tags: seo, google, domains, keywords

I am going to choose a domain name for my business. For that I am going to use joined words in my domain name.

For example, let's say my keywords are "painting" and "goa" and also that `paintinggoa.com` is not available to register.

In this case if I choose `paintingoa.com` is it good? Is it good for SEO purposes?

How will Google treat this domain name?

Comment: The answers provided also apply to misspellings of keywords used in domains too. There's not much of an advantage anymore in using keyword rich domain names unless they come to be recognized as a brand-name (like `twitter.com`).

Answer (score 6):

It's good but not as good as you might think. Google recently devalued exact match domains so they no longer carry a lot of weight in their algorithm. So your on-page factors and off-site factors (incoming links) will have a greater effect on your SEO efforts.

Answer (score 2):

This technique with keywords to choose a domain name is totally old fashioned and not really good for SEO. If I were you, I will choose a domain name as a brand, the best choice you can do today. Therefore, choose a brand name and buy the associated domain name.

Comment: Two fine answers, just 2 seconds apart!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Zistoloen and @John Conde, but I also have my own opinion.
`Paintingoa.com` will be a great domain for this case. If these keywords represent the essence of your website, you should use them. It should help with site ranking in Google.
At least, it is better than using keywords, which are not related to your site.